# Clickable image with sprites

Tags: html, anchor, css-sprites

So I've got a series of clickable images in my page. I've tried to optimise this by generating a single image containing all the images I need and I intend to use sprites to select the one I want. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to add anchor tags to the sprites though?

So I'm after a clickable HTML element that supports sprites, preferably without using JavaScript. I can do it using JavaScript but I'd prefer to avoid it.

OK, here's my code, what there is:

```
.touringEscorted {
    height:125px;
    width: 214px;
    background-image: url('/Images/Travel2New/ToursImages/ToursBanners.jpg');
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.touringNew {
    height:125px;
    width: 214px;
    background-image: url('/Images/Travel2New/ToursImages/ToursBanners.jpg');
    background-position: -10px 0;
}
```

I've tried

```
<a href="#"><div class="touringEscorted"></a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" class="touringEscorted">&nbsp;</a>
```

and several others. Seems there's no way to use sprites/background images and anchor tags at the same time. Am I right?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't got any at the moment, I can post my css but that isn't relevant to the question. I'm after the HTML markup, tried a couple of options but none have worked. All I want is a clickable HTML element that supports sprites

Comment: Your question is weird, as in "supporting sprites". I suppose you're misunderstanding something. Can't help you if you don't post what you've got already and what you've tried.

Comment: You're missing the `px` part. `background-position: -10px 0;` would be right

Comment: if you want to give 'a' tag a width and a height you have to declare it as a display:block;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok then :

```
<a href="#" class="touringEscorted"></a>
```

Should work, but adding `display:block;` to the CSS :

```
.touringEscorted {
    height:125px;
    width: 214px;
    background-image: url('/Images/Travel2New/ToursImages/ToursBanners.jpg');
    background-position: 0 0;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
<a class="sprite sprite1" href="javascript:;">Link Text</a>
```

---

```
sprite {
  display: block;
  background: url(path/to/image/file.ext);
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
sprite1 {
  width: WWpx;
  height: HHpx;
  background-position: -NNpx - MMpx;
}
```

Comment: Spot on! I think I was missing the display:block! Will mark as answer ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Google consider off screen text as spammy? I came up with a modification. I put the link in another element, in this case a table. I added the background image class in the element and in the link like this:

CSS code:

```
.sprite{ 
    background: url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat top left; 
}   
.sprite.termite { 
    background-position: 0px -499px; 
    width: 150px; height: 113px;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<td class="td sprite termite">
    <a href="termite-photos.html" title="termite control" class="sprite termite"></a>
</td>
```

It renders the image in the table perfectly and clicks!