# How to make an image link using CSS sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have an internship and my task to try and create a website using only CSS Sprites. Below is the image I'm using, and I found a way to only show the icons I want using CSS. But now, im trying to find out how to link them. For example, If i just want the facebook icon link how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: You have to search online and try something. You cannot just ask others to show you how to do it. We can help you fix problems if you can't get it to work. You won't learn nearly as much if someone just gives you the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clickable image with sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215310/clickable-image-with-sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard `<a>` element to create links. Then with the css you can set the background image/position to each of them. Something similar (You have to learn how to do it):

```html
<style>
  .SocialNav > a {
    background-image: ...;
  }

  .Facebook {
    background-position: ...;
  }

  .Twitter {
    background-position: ...;
  }
</style>

<nav class="SocialNav">
  <a href="https://" class="Facebook" aria-label="Facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://" class="Twitter" aria-label="Twitter"></a>
</nav>
```

You have to elaborate my example with these resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/